# Fetch API is not receiving Express error JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I've built a simple REST api and now I'm trying to connect a front-end client to it. As part of my error handling process I want to send any server side errors as a JSON object to my client, so that I can display appropriate error messages for the user.

An example of my back-end express code:

```js
try {
    const newPost = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
      author: author._id,
    });
    await newPost.save();
    res.json(newPost);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({ err });
  }
```

When testing, The `console.log(err)` in my `catch` block prints out an error object if post validation fails, e.g.

```
errors: {
    title: ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.
...
}
```

Here is an example of how I am communicating with the API from my front-end client.

```js
fetch(url, options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status !== 200) throw new Error(res);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

The `console.log` res picks up the following object:

```
body: ReadableStream
   locked: false
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3001/posts"
```

Despite my back-end issuing a `json(err)`, this does not seem to get picked up in the above response. So how can I get `fetch` to pick up the error object that I am sending from the back end?

Comment: *Despite my back-end issuing a json(err), this does not seem to get picked up in the above* that will be in the body? Does the body not contain this data?

Comment: @Liam nope, I've edited my original post to show it just has a 'Locked' property.

Comment: You have to read the body with `err.json()` or `err.text()`.

Comment: @jabaa could you give me an example of how this would look? As currently I'm getting `err.json` is not a function

Comment: Now I see the problem. You are creating and throwing an error with `throw new Error(res);`. The constructor expects a message. The error response is stringified and additional data is lost.

Comment: @jabaa how can I pass the message that is sent via `res.json()` on the server side to the client side?

Comment: It's in `res` but lost after `new Error(res)`. That means you are actually passing the message to the client side and discarding it at the client side. There are different ways to keep the error message. You could create a string containing it, or you could throw the error response object `throw res.json();` instead of a new error object `throw new Error(res);`.